# How to continue outer loop from inner loop inside Laravel Blade template? (Laravel 6.x or above)

Tags: php, laravel

I want to continue outer for loop from inner for loop in my laravel blade. Fortunately, I am able to achieved it by adding 2 inside the continue parenthesis as  `@continue(2)`. e.g.

```
 @foreach($students as $student)           {{-- Outer Loop --}}
     @foreach($student['marks'] as $mark)  {{-- Inner Loop --}}
         @if($mark == 50 )
             @continue(2)       {{-- This will continue the outer loop --}}
         @endIf
     @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

I know it is possible in core PHP as in [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php)
However in laravel I am not able to find any documentations that explain this feature. The doc [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops) explains only the condition inside @continue(*condition*) and @break(*condition*).

So is there any laravel documentation, so that I can confirm what I am doing is correct?

Comment: Looking at your snippet, @break would do the same thing.

Comment: @nice_dev Yeah, this is just for demonstration,  it would make sense if I added few lines of code after inner for loop

Comment: Then you should do it for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

It can be something like that:

```
@foreach($students as $student)           {{-- Outer Loop --}}
     @php
        $has_mark_50 = FALSE;
     @endphp
     @foreach($student['marks'] as $mark)  {{-- Inner Loop --}}
         @if($mark == 50)
             @php
                $has_mark_50 = TRUE;
             @endphp
             @break       {{-- This will break the inner loop --}}
         @endIf
     @endforeach
     @if ($has_mark_50)
         @continue    {{-- This will continue the outer loop --}}
     @endIf
 @endforeach
```

`@continue(something)` means "continue if 'something' is true".

Comment: I don't think in @continue(something) , 'something' need not always be a  boolean, It can be numeric. If I use numeric more than 2 like @continue(4) it gives error as "Cannot 'continue' 4 levels". It means the numeric value is treated as level number of the loops. But I don't find this in Laravel Documentation